# Describe the congruence classes in $F[x]/(x)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Describe the congruence classes in $F[x]/(x)$.

I am not really sure where to start here or how to describe them at all.

Comment: Is F a ring and F[x] the polynomial ring over F?

Comment: Recall the definition of congruence classes and equivalence relations. The congruence class here will partition $F[x]/[x]$ based on a equivalence relation.

Comment: Alternatively the congruence classes in $F[x]/[x]$ is described as a sub-rings/fields in $F[x]/[x]$ therefore any sub-rings/fields implies a homomorphism and a congruence class as well as vice versa.

Comment: Any two polynomials are "congruent modulo $x$" precisely if they have the same constant term.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean $F[x]/(x)$, where $F$ is a ring. There are two ways to go about this; one is arguably more "rigorous" and the other pushes some details under the rug.

**Heuristic approach**: This is the intuitive way of thinking about what happens when you modulo by a polynomial. One can think $F[x]/(x)$ as the "set of all polynomials with coefficients in $F$, but insisting that the relation $x = 0$ holds. Thus wherever an $x$ appears, let it disappear. In this case, a polynomial $a_nx^n + \cdots + a_0$ is reduced to just $a_0$, so this polynomial belongs in the equivalence class of $a_0$. But we observe that we can do this for *any* $a_0 \in F$, leading us to believe that the the equivalence class representatives are all the elements of $F$, with the equivalence class itself being the set of all polynomials with constant term being that element (this is easily seen to be an equivalence relation). One can clean up this approach and make it an actual proof.

**Formal approach**: Every ideal is the kernel of some homomorphism, namely the reduction homomorphism. Thus if we can identify the image of this homomorphism, the First Isomorphism Theorem gives a clean expression for $F[x]/(x)$. Following the line of thought in the previous paragraph, the homomorphism is perhaps $\phi : F[x] \to F$ given by $\phi(f) = f(0)$, i.e. evaluation at $x = 0$. One easily checks that this is a homomorphism. To see that $\ker(\phi) = (x)$, note that if $f \in \ker(\phi)$, then $f(0) = 0$, so the polynomial has no constant term. Thus we can factor out an $x$, showing that $f \in (x)$. Conversely, if $f \in (x)$, then clearly $f(0) = 0$. Thus the reduction homomoprhism is indeed evaluation at 0. The image is easily seen to be all of $F$, since for any $\alpha \in F$, we can take the constant polynomial $\alpha$ and evaluate it at $x = 0$ to obtain $\alpha$. By the First Isomorphism Theorem,
$$F[x]/(x) \simeq F.$$
From the homomorphism, one deduces that the equivalence classes are exactly those described in the heuristic approach.

In general, one needs to be careful about the justifying the First Isomorphism Theorem steps. In particular, one does not always "obviously" have the kernel of the equaling the ideal. We were lucky enough in this case to have the simplest polynomial to work with, but in general we can't always "factor" out an arbitrary polynomial. If we are working in a field, this is more do-able, since the Division Algorithm is on our side. For example, try finding the "famous" ring that $\mathbb R[x]/(x^2 + 1)$ is isomorphic to.

Comment: Nice, +1 for including the heuristic approach